# How can eosio.token (v1.4.0) compile?

Tags: eosio.token

I'm attempting to follow this guide, which seems official: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/token-contract and which begins by grabbing the v1.4.0 branch of the EOSIO contracts:

```
git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts --branch v1.4.0 --single-branch
```

in looking at the code I discovered that line 133 contains a reference to `same_payer`, what seems like an undeclared variable (if it's declared, I don't see where):

```
$ head -n 133 eosio.token.cpp |tail -n 1
```

> to_acnts.modify( to, same_payer, [&]( auto& a ) {

now, I decided to pull the code from github directly, for this version:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/v1.4.0/contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.cpp

but curiously, that file is totally different (to begin with, it only has 120 lines) and contains a `0` instead:

> to_acnts.modify( to, 0, [&]( auto& a ) {

so I have 2 questions:

1) am I pulling the wrong version from github (via the link) and if so, what is the proper way to do it? and

2) how can the code compile when it's making a reference to a variable that hasn't been declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using outdated `eosio.cdt`. `eosio::same_payer` is declared in `multi_index.hpp`.

Upgrade `eosio.cdt` from [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/releases).

The latest version of `eosio.cdt` is 1.4.1.

Comment: I have 1.4.1 installed (`brew info eosio.cdt` produces "eosio.cdt: stable 1.4.1 (bottled)")

Comment: actually, that makes sense, if I look in `/usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.4.1/opt/eosio.cdt/include/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp` I see the definition.  so that explains why the code compiles.  but that brings up another perplexing point: the guide I'm following uses v1.4.0 of the contract, which seems to know about the new `same_payer`.  that would mean it's very current.  is 1.4.0 then later than what's on the `master` branch?

Comment: @ekkis Do you mean `contracts/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp` in the `master` branch of github.com/EOSIO/eos? It was written for `eosiocpp` (not `eosio-cpp`) which is old compiler, but now `contracts` directory in `eos` repository is used for testing purpose only. `contracts` directory will be removed in `1.6.0` release and testing would use libraries provided by `eosio.cdt` repository.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to understand whether the v1.4.0 version of the contracts that the guide uses is later or earlier than the master branch.  I guess if it's a branch then it has yet to be merged into master and thus must be more recent.  that would mean that the guide expects the latest version of things, which would be a good thing